# How to download apps without a wireless data plan

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi

I bought an i7500, no data plan. I had assumed that connecting to my router would allow me to download apps from the marketplace; apparently not. I get a message about not being able to connect via the SIM data plan.

Is there a way for me to download and install apps without actually getting a data plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use sites like SlideMe.org, which "mirror" many Market apps and allow you to download them without registering your Android device. Beware of stolen apps, though (i.e. paid apps which are available for free). You can also use the Marketplace app with only a wireless router in range.

Answer (score 0):

xda developers has a guide for this. See [Guide: Using Android Without a Data Plan](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=731752). I cannot verify these instructions but the comments in the xda thread seem positive.

Below is the section regarding getting apps:

> The easiest way to find apps is to type the app name and apk into
>   google, but most of the time, this does not work (and is illegal for
>   paid apps, unless you get it from the dev directly). Since this
>   doesn't usually work, you can get apps using a special avd and the
>   android emulator.
>
> 1. Download/Setup the Android SDK and Download the accessmarket.rar file (originally found at
>      http://tech-droid.blogspot.com/2009/...-emulator.html)
> 2. Copy the contents of accessmarket.rar to C:/Users//.android/avd/ - you might have to enable "show hidden files"
>      in folder options to see the .android folder
> 3. Edit C:/Users//.android/avd/AndEmu.ini, and change the username in the file to your username
> 4. Start SDKSetup.exe, then click Virtual Devices, launch the device called "AndEmu"
> 5. Once this is started, download ASTRO file manager from market (it works in this emulator!) - ASTRO will allow you to backup the apks for
>      apps that you download from the market. (NOTE: for protected/private
>      apps, you can use Titanium Backup to back them up)
>
>    5.5. You can download any app from the market, and back it up
> 6. The apps you backup will be backed up to /sdcard/backups/apps/
> 7. You can use one of the following adb commands to pull these files from the emulator:
>
>    adb pull /sdcard/backups/apps/ /AndApps
>
>    This will download all of your backed up apps to a folder on your
>      root drive called AndApps
>
>    or
>
>    adb pull /sdcard/backups/apps/.apk /AndApps/.apk
>
>    This will copy a single apk of your choosing to /AndApps/
> 8. After you do this, you need to copy the apk to your sdcard (either by taking the card out, or using the SD Share widget), and then you
>      can install it to your phone with ASTRO
>
> Note: Special Applications:
>
> Some applications like to let you download themes and such within the
>   app, without any other source. Most of these applications store files
>   on a folder named after the app (com.something.something) so you can
>   download the stuff within the app on the emulator, and backup the
>   folder on the emu's sd card and put it on your phone.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Aside from installation problems, when I finally get it running, Google refuses to acknowledge that I have a device.

Comment: So you get the market but no apps can be downloaded? Since then have you tried signing in to the market from a PC?

Comment: I can download, install, and run apps from the market on my emulated device, but Google reports no phones. I even set the OS to 1.6 and 2.3, still no go. Yes, I signed in from a PC since then.

Comment: any other ideas?

Comment: I suggest editing your question with things you've tried... If nothing else this will bring your question back to the top and will get a few more eyes on it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, install [Amazon App Store](http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/get-appstore/android). Its the only app store on planet which could compete with official Android Market. It also provides one paid app for free daily.