# Do you need a data plan to install Amazon's App Store?

Tags: amazon-appstore

And does the http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/get-appstore/android have the same exact apps as on Android Market?

Followup from [How to download apps without a wireless data plan](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16501/how-to-download-apps-without-a-wireless-data-plan)

Comment: The exact apps exist in both only insofar as the developer(s) have submitted their apps to both.

Comment: This also depends on the device probably. You can download from the Market on devices that have no data plans provided that the device itself can operate without one. The question you've linked to is probably more appropriately phrased as "How do I bypass the SIM requirement on my device"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your device is allowed to install apps from *Unknown Sources* (Check Settings), there's no need of data plan to install [Amazon AppStore](http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/get-appstore/android). Carriers don't (and, can't) lock every third-party app to promote their data plan. In fact, it may become a legal issue for them.

[Amazon AppStore](http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/get-appstore/android) isn't exact copy of Android Market, but it has really a large no. of app collection, thanks to e-commerce giant. Its the only app store for Android which could compete with official Android Market. In fact, its a threat for Android Market.